# Issue with Nginx configuration : location and directory

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration, directory

I have the following simple server block :

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;
        location / {
           *****root test/a/;*****
                index index.htm;
                autoindex on;
        }
```

The line concerns me is with where a put stars, I denoted root as `test/a/`, and it is working well, I can reach the index from a browser.

But if I choose root as `/test/a/;` it doesn't work, I get a 404 error.

I saw everyone is using a "/" in front of the directory of the root, from tutorials and in this website.

Why it doesn't work with me, any ideas? My system is Linux v3.18.11+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `/` in front of the directory, you need to use full path from the root of the server.

For example:

```
root /var/www/test/a/;
```

Without the `/`, it will use the path specified during compile time with the `--prefix` option for the prefix for the `root` directive.

You should also use `alias` directive inside `location` blocks, that doesn't cause issues with `location` blocks that are elsewhere than website root.